# Windows Batch case sensitive string variable

Tags: c#, .net, string, batch-file, variables

I want to SET variable in Windows Batch. This variable will be a string.

I do this:

```
SET foo=ExampleString
```

Later I want to use this variable in .NET Core application and there I got string which is "examplestring", but I want to get it case sensitive. Can somebody help me?

Is it .NET specific question or Windows Batch?

**UPDATE**

So If my ExmapleString will be a ConnectionString something like this:

> Server=FOONAME\SQLEXPRESS,11433;Database=FooDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true

And I got this:

> server=fooname\sqlexpress,11433;database=foodatabase;trusted_connection=true;multipleactiveresultsets=true;database

c# code which I use:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("foo");
```

Semicolon will be the problem?

Comment: You need to share the code which gets value from batch to C# code. Single line of code doesn't give any indication around his things are implemented and what is wrong there.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Okey, I got it. So it's .NET specific question.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I Updated my question, can you read it again? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So thank you all the comment section people who are help me.

If I do this in batch file:

```
set foo=Server=FOONAME\SQLEXPRESS,11433;Database=FooDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

And if I do this in C# application:

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%foo%")
```

This is work!